# Enable/Disable Log4j2 Marker

Tags: log4j2, markers

I am using a Log4j2 Marker called "SQL" in different sub-modules of my monolith application.
I would like to know if there is a way to enable/disable this marker independently of the logger level.

In case it is not possible, it would mean I would have to declare several logger entries (one per sub-module) in my log4j2.xml configuration file with the right level to enable/disable it. Would you have a better way in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as Markers are always enabled or disabled independently of logging levels. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <MarkerFilter marker="SQL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
             filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
 </Configuration>
```

will cause all log events with an SQL Marker to be logged independent of their logging level because they have been accepted by the Marker Filter before any log level has been evaluated. Placing the filter under the appender, logger or appender reference will require the logging level at those points to be evaluated based on the rules of the particular component.

Comment: My question makes a lot of sense since I did not know it was possible to define a MarketFilter outside an Appender. Thanks for the information !

Comment: I apologize for using that wording. What I meant to imply is that if you think of log levels as a horizontal "slice" then Markers would be a vertical "slice". They both can filter log events but in a completely different and mostly independent way. And yes, Filters can be specified globally, on a Logger, on an Appender Reference or on an Appender.